# How do nutritional supplement companies come up with the recommended dosage?

Tags: supplements

Is there a standard or guideline to this? For instance, is there a prototypical person with an average weight they design dosage parameters for?

Comment: surprisingly - the wiki articles I can find only mention "healthy people" US: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_Daily_Intake UK: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_Reference_Values - the only metric I see is "2,000 calories per day" *shrug*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies; however in general it is based on a healthy individual ages 4 - 50 consuming 2,000 calories a day.

The [LiveStrong web site](http://www.livestrong.com/article/85706-recommended-daily-intake-vitamins/) states:

> The daily dose of vitamins health officials recommend varies by life
>   stage. These groups are defined by people's gender, age and, in the
>   case of females, whether they are pregnant or lactating. To maintain
>   body metabolism, everyone needs the essential vitamins A, C, D, E and
>   K and the eight vitamins in the B family. The recommended daily value
>   printed on vitamin supplement labels is based on a 2,000-calorie diet
>   and represents the average vitamin intake adequate for those age 4 to
>   50. The U.S. Department of Agriculture (USDA) recommendations are higher, however, and represent optimum doses.

There reference to the USDA allows us to get a [much more granular view](http://www.iom.edu/Activities/Nutrition/SummaryDRIs/~/media/Files/Activity%20Files/Nutrition/DRIs/5_Summary%20Table%20Tables%201-4.pdf) and covers the varying life stage groups.

If you take a life stage group and what the average weight is for that given group, that would define your prototypical person within that category that they base their figures on.